# Tags javascript setting maximum

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a JavaScript i would like to add the maximum tags option to be 6 only and no duplicates this is the code i have so far

```
             <div id="tags">
                <span>php</span>
                <span>c++</span>
                <span>jquery</span>
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
              </div>
<script>
$(function(){ // DOM ready    
  // ::: TAGS BOX    
  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout : function() {
      var txt= this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,''); // allowed characters
      if(txt) $("<span/>",{text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
      this.value="";
    },
    keyup : function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter|space (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if(/(188|13|32)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout();
    }
  });
  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    if(confirm("Remove "+ $(this).text() +"?")) $(this).remove();
  });

});
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/hehurot/5/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: Select2 is better right... Why don't you use it?

Comment: am sorry what ?

Comment: [Select2](https://select2.github.io) - Look at this.

Comment: can i also get suggestions from a database using that ?

Comment: Use `$('#tags span').length` to find out how many tags there are. If it's 6, don't add a new tag.

Comment: @craftx27 See the remote options.. Yes!

Comment: nice thank you so much

Comment: @PraveenKumar i am unable to use this plug in nicely could you help out if possible

Comment: @craftx27 OKay...

Comment: @craftx27 See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Select2](https://select2.github.io) to do this:

- Uses tag style.
- No repetitions.
- Maximum of 3 selections.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $(".select2").select2({
          maximumSelectionLength: 3,
          width: 350
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select name="tags" id="tags" class="select2" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
      <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
      <option value="CPP">C++</option>
      <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".select2").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 3,
    width: 350
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select name="tags" id="tags" class="select2" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
  <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
  <option value="CPP">C++</option>
  <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
</select>
```

**Demo:** [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cegofokemu/edit?html,output)

Comment: this is pretty good :) :) 
wont this be slow when i have to load lets say more then 2000 `<option></option>`

Comment: isnt there away i can use `LIKE %` to look for stuffs using ajaxs with select2

Comment: @craftx27 Hey, the `%%` is available. Looking into the APIs. Give me some time.

Comment: its okay i got it